# intellij grep for getting the whole json log

Tags: intellij-idea, grep

Some of the applications I work on logs to the console as JSON so it looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2022-07-07T11:06:58.003",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "thread" : "http-nio-8080-exec-10",
  "logger" : "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
  "message" : "FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 142 ms"
}
```

I have grep console installed on intellij, how do I filter this to get the whole JSON. When I put in something like `.*info.*` I only get the `"level" : "INFO"` part and not the other keys and values.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole/issues

Comment: Try `{[^{}]*info[^{}]*}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it didn't work on intellij, although I tested this on regexr and it seemed to work,

Comment: Probably, some Android related thing. Try `\{[^{}]*info[^{}]*\}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\{[^{}]*info[^{}]*\}
```

The regex matches

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `info` - a fixed string
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `\}` - a `}` char.

Note that `{` does not need escaping in many flavors, but in (at least) TRE and Android regex patterns it must be escaped.